# What does "alpha floor" mean?

Tags: aircraft-systems

I was talking to a pilot, and he said that the alpha floor had been activated, and I did not have time to ask him to explain this. So, can you clarify my doubt, please?

Comment: Related: [Just wondering how you can get an Airbus into Alpha Floor?](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Aerospace-Aviation-2437/Airbus.htm)

Comment: Who do you work for? This is a concerning question.

Answer (score 8):

Alpha floor is a thrust function which provides TOGA thrust regardless of thrust lever position in Airbus. From [Airbus Technical Digest FAST 20](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0ahUKEwiq2a3QzpLKAhWGuRoKHcesB4EQFghXMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.airbus.com%2Fsupport%2Fpublications%2F%3FeID%3Dmaglisting_push%26tx_maglisting_pi1%255BdocID%255D%3D41128&usg=AFQjCNH2zsVyKqTa-8CM5FDVo3vX83T7hw&cad=rja):

> Alpha Floor is a low speed protection (in normal law) which is purely an
>   autothrust mode. When activated, it provides TOGA thrust. As the aircraft
>   decelerates into the alpha protection range, the Alpha Floor is activated,
>   even if the autothrust is disengaged. Activation is roughly proportional to
>   the rate of deceleration.
>
> ... at low speeds, if a rapid avoidance manoeuvre is required to avoid terrain, windshear or another aircraft, it is safe to rapidly pull the sidestick fully aft and/or bank and hold it there. The aircraft will pitch up
>   to max Alpha, engage TOGA thrust and climb away.

Note that this protection is only available under normal law and [is lost under alternate law](http://www.airbusdriver.net/airbus_fltlaws.htm).

Comment: However apparently A310 already had alpha-floor, though it did not yet have fly-by-wire nor normal law. Not sure whether A300 had it too, but it probably did; A310 is not that much different from A300.

Comment: @JanHudec Looks like A300 [did have alpha floor](http://lessonslearned.faa.gov/ll_main.cfm?TabID=2&LLID=64&LLTypeID=2).

Comment: How should the rapid avoidance manoeuvre look in an Aircraft without alpha floor?

Comment: @curious_cat The pilot will have to add power using the throttle lever, and use the stick to reach the desired attitude without stalling.

Answer (score 1):

When the angle of attack limit is reached, a value which is dependent on the configuration and longitudinal wind gradient, the FMGC receives the order from the FAC. This order is only taken into account by the FMGC, if:

- Landing gear shock absorbers are extended at takeoff
- and up to 100 ft at landing

If these conditions are met, the A/THR is engaged, and the Alpha floor protection is activated. The A/THR is commanded max. consequently.

The only way to cancel alpha floor is by disengaging the A/THR function.